# IndexedDB write to database fails in Webview 66.0.3359.126

Tags: android, webview, indexeddb

My indexedDB application was perfectly working on previous version of Webview (55.xx), however after system automatically upgraded to the newest version of Webview (66.xx) something went wrong.

I have checked every single possibility but instead of getting any error on put method, it shows success.

This is the code that is failing in Android webview (66.xx):

```
var request = indexedDB.open("library");

request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
  // The database did not previously exist, so create object stores and indexes.
  var db = request.result;
  var store = db.createObjectStore("books", {keyPath: "isbn"});
  var titleIndex = store.createIndex("by_title", "title", {unique: true});
  var authorIndex = store.createIndex("by_author", "author");

  // Populate with initial data. ==> (Code is failing on this point without throwing any error)
  store.put({title: "Quarry Memories", author: "Fred", isbn: 123456});
  store.put({title: "Water Buffaloes", author: "Fred", isbn: 234567});
  store.put({title: "Bedrock Nights", author: "Barney", isbn: 345678});
};

request.onsuccess = function() {
  db = request.result;
};
```

I am using Android 5.0 version :|

Comment: Are you listening for error events? Given that you do not specify a version, are you sure the code is even running? Where the is db variable set? How do you know the db variable is set by the time you use it? Please provide more information.

Comment: Through console, debugging

Comment: I am also running this code in console by opening via Chrome://inspect to check on which point code is not working, however this code has been tested in browser also; code is working fine in browser and also in old webview(55)

Comment: I have same problem for getting value from IndexedDb Can you help me please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662542/how-to-access-indexeddb-from-storage-in-webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=838816

The fix is merged. We must wait newt version 67 the May 29th, 2018

https://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar

[Chrome on Android: Granted Quota for IndexedDB suddenly almost 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50019306/chrome-on-android-granted-quota-for-indexeddb-suddenly-almost-0)