# No internet connection in cordova app on some android devices

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic app that has been in the app store for over a year. Now suddenly multiple people are reporting that the app doesn't work. They can't get past the loading screen, which is expected if the phone doesn't have an internet connection.

I have set all the necessary settings in the index.html and config.xml files:

index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: content: https://ssl.gstatic.com ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' localhost:35729; media-src * content: cdvphotolibrary:; img-src * content: data: blob: cdvphotolibrary:">
```

config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
```

I have not changed anything on those settings recently.

The app uses https://sentry.io for error logging, but I also cannot see any errors being sent to sentry, which means that either there are no errors, or the app does not have internet access.

The problem only exists on Android, we have not gotten a single report from iOS users. The Android phones tend to be a little bit older (Android 5 and Android 6), and we had one user report that the error was resolved after upgrading to the latest version.

The only option now is to push out a new release with improved error handling to be able to pinpoint the problem, but it's hard because I can't reproduce it on my test devices and I also can't seem to get any feedback from the devices.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was not directly related to a connection issue, but rather to the fact that the app couldn't store the credentials to indexedDB, which lead to all the requests failing because they were unauthenticated.

The issue is described here and should be resolved in a couple of days when chrome releases a new version: [Chrome on Android: Granted Quota for IndexedDB suddenly almost 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50019306/chrome-on-android-granted-quota-for-indexeddb-suddenly-almost-0)

The sentry HTTP request failed, probably because of a similar issue. This could be resolved by setting `allowSecretKey` to true.

Comment: Please how can I set allowSecretKey to true? I have a similar problem